# Read a "Content" file in ASP.NET Core 1.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, embedded-resource

I'm trying to get a list of all my bundled files from Bundle & Minifier (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.BundlerMinifier), but I cant seam to read a file marked as "Content" in Build action using ASP.NET Core 1.1...

[image]

The content of my bundleconfig.json looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/lib/_bundles/default.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
      "wwwroot/lib/jsrender/jsrender.js",
      "wwwroot/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
      "wwwroot/lib/numeral/src/numeral.js",
      "wwwroot/lib/numeral/src/locales/da-dk.js",     
    ],
    "minify": {
      "enabled": true,
      "renameLocals": true
    }
  },
]
```

... and the build action is set to "Content".

My code for reading the file is...

```
Assembly _assembly;
StreamReader _textStreamReader;
_assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
_textStreamReader = new StreamReader(_assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("bundleconfig.json"));
var j = JObject.Parse(_textStreamReader.ReadToEnd());
JArray files = (JArray)j[0]["inputFiles"];
List<string> filesList = files.Select(c => (string)c).ToList();
```

But I get a null exeption in the `new StreamReader(_assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("bundleconfig.json"));` line.

Any suggestions how to read this file?

Thanks

Comment: GetManifestResourceStream is used to load compiled resources, i.e. files that become part of the assembly code. Have you just tried loading your files using some part of System.IO, e.g. File?

Answer (score 1):

You try to same that:
In File **project.json** add setting:

```
"publishOptions": {
    "includeFiles": [ "appsettings.json", "bundleconfig.json" ]
},
```

And in file **Program.cs**:

```
var bundleconfig = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    .AddJsonFile("bundleconfig.json", optional: true)
                    .Build();
```

Comment: I don't see a "project.json" in Core 1.1?

Comment: Also if I try your code, I get an error .... FormatException: Could not parse the JSON file. Error on line number '1': '[' .... and I can't edit the bundleconfig.json without breaking bundle & minifier.

Comment: maybe you create project don't exactly. I have created project demo: https://www.screencast.com/t/1DId8lRF

Comment: It seams like the "project.json" has been removed in VS2017RC (latets version) ... http://www.talkingdotnet.com/bye-bye-project-json-xproj-welcome-back-csproj/

Comment: OMG. I don't know it :). I don't make sure VS2017RC good. If you using it, maybe you need try to config .csproj work same when have file "project.json"